# What may be causing C Drive storage increases of more than 20GB overnight?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, sleep, disk-space

### Desciption

Windows 10 user here. As the title says, somehow overnight my C drive has been populated with 20GB of data overnight. The situation happened recently, and is something new, as it has not happened in the past.

My C Drive has normally around 25GB of free space left, but after going to **sleep** this space shrank to around 3GB (in fact the system broke down when I woke it up in the morning).

> "broke down" means not returning back to Windows Desktop as usual but to become bluescreen anouncing "Your device has met problem, need reboot"(translated into English), and the `terminal code` was `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT`

Is this caused by some kind of virus or perhaps some user settings?

Before:

[image: Normal capacity]

Bluescreen during waking up:

[image: Bluescreen]

After:

[image: Capacity after sleep]

What's interesting is that if I shutdown and reboot, the free space will return to normal once more.

### My Effort (or the Details)

I've tried to detect what happened using [SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/) but saw nothing out of the ordinary.

Before:
[image: SpaceSniffer: normal]

After:
[image: SpaceSniffer: abnormal]

I've also checked Windows EventViewer, and I remembered that there was no event during the sleep.

---

**new observation**：

- I let my pc sleep(click Power->Sleep in) for just a while(around 10 minutes) before waking it up(by pressing keyboard), the situation remained the same(this time the space left around 5GB).
- Directly reboot won't let the free space come back, only shutdown + boot would do.

Maybe it's some system error? (Oh I should check BSOD Error)

> Thank you all very much for help!!! I would try those methods and report them if I'm free (tons of exams and deadlines are coming (´;ω;`)

Comment: nothing weird, except maybe that warning?

Comment: Hello, why do you assume virus automatically? Do you really think a virus would love to make itself so obvious that it removes most of remaining disk space for no apparent reason? Anyways, try another app for disk visualization, e.g. WinDirStat, maybe it won't have that warning/error.

Comment: "Is it caused by some kind of virus or just some settings?" - Unlikely; Extremely unlikely but the information you have provided isn't enough to determine what is using your disk space.  A wild guess is the hibernation file.

Comment: thanks. And i've also looked into the Windows Event Viewer and there's no event during the sleep period. maybe i should focus on that warning/ hibernation file (but this situation just did not occurred in the past... ( Ꙭ)

Comment: I thought about hibernation file too, but a) yyou mentioned sleep not hibernation (please confirm tht's the case) and b) both screens have that file (`hiberfil.sys`) with the same size, I don't think it'd randomly grow so much.

Comment: What Windows Store applications, other than was preinstalled, specifically larger applications.

Comment: Did an update complete overnight? If so, there might be a new folder, Windows.old, and the WinSxS folder may also have grown. *Do not try to delete those folders or their contents manually.* Instead, perform disk cleanup.

Comment: Open settings, type storage and use it to ID biggest space-mongers and clean them up, let the tool handle that, don't go manually delete.

Comment: @Destroy666 Oh, I've confirmed that its **sleep** not hibernation, and as we can see the `hiberfil.sys` did not changed. (So maybe hibernation is not the reason?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not. As I wrote, I think your next step should be to use a better program to check folder sizes, run it also as admin to additionally avoid some potential permission problems, then there won't be any speculation.

Comment: A simple tool might be [windirstat](https://windirstat.net/) which will show you disk usage by folder and let you click through to see the usage by subfolder.

Comment: @Elucidator-xrb - Try and disable hibernation.  Windows 10 and Windows 11 by default supports hybrid sleep.  I would also NOT try to put your machine to sleep, since 25GB in my opinion, is not enough space to dump everything in memory to disk.  Based on the memory management error, I suspect you have a memory issue, and the storage space while a concern is likely not related to system crashing while booting. Without a precise **English** translation of WinDBG analysis output of the .dmp I can't help resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I think the reason is indeed hibernation file.

I found its real size up to 31GB (which well fits my physical memory size). So I delete it with command `powercfg -h off`.(though I'm sure I've already shut off windows hibernation in gui... that's weird)

> Spacesniffer only detect 12GB of herbernation file `hiberfile.sys`... It appears that this software indeed has a defect.